# MVC4 jQuery Mobile DateTime Picker Format to MM/YYYY Only

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, mobile, formatting, datepicker

I need to be able to enter dates, but need the jQuery Mobile datepicker to only be able to accept MM/YYYY data. Help with this issue would be great. Thanks.

Here's what I have...

VIEW:

```
 <h3>Search Dates</h3>
 <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SearchBeginDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchBeginDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SearchBeginDate)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SearchEndDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
         @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SearchEndDate)
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SearchEndDate)
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
```

MODEL:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Begin Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime SearchBeginDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/yyyy}")]
    [Display(Name = "End Date")]
    public DateTime SearchEndDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HTML5 input type property of 'date.' That will allow the native controls for date and time.

```
<input type="date" />
```